# What are the differences among Cave Story versions?

Tags: version-differences, cave-story

What are the critical differences between the various releases of Cave Story (PC, WiiWare, DSiWare, 3DS)? In particular, I already have a copy (of Cave Story+) on Steam from the Humble Indie Bundle 4, but the 3DS release sounds like the most intriguing—is the 3DS remake worth the $30 if I already own a version?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### TL:DR

Cave Story 3D (for the 3DS) is a 3D remake of the 2004 original where all the characters and levels are in 3D perspective. There are also a few "easter eggs" for fans of the older games.

---

## The Full Story

There have been numerous new versions and [unofficial ports](http://www.cavestory.org/downloads_game.php) of Cave Story since the original was released in 2004, so assuming you don't want to know the specifics of the [TI-83 plus calculator port](http://www.ticalc.org/archives/files/fileinfo/412/41258.html), I'll just mention the differences of the five official versions.

### Cave Story ("The Original", Platform: PC, circa 2004)

The original freeware version, with 100% original awesome.

### Cave Story (Platform: WiiWare, circa 2010)

A new and updated version of Cave Story, with revamped graphics, music, and new playmodes.

**Changes include:**

- Updated "progressive" graphics (480p) and new music, with the option to use the "old school" versions of both
- Five new playmodes, including Boss Rush, and the ability to play as Curly Brace
- Larger range of difficulty settings

### Cave Story (Platform: DSiWare, circa 2011)

A DS port of the 2004 original, with some of the new features from the WiiWare version thrown in.

**Changes include:**

- Uses second screen as a map and inventory viewer
- A modified version of the "Boss Rush" game mode included in the WiiWare version
- An unlockable music player

### Cave Story+ (Platform: Steam, circa 2011)

The awesomeness returns to PCs, with many of the WiiWare features included, plus some other things.

**Changes include:**

- An HD graphical overhaul, with music introduced in the WiiWare version, and the option to use the "old school" versions as well
- All game modes introduced with WiiWare version
- All new game mode "Wind Fortress"
- Native USB controller support

### Cave Story 3D (Platform: 3DS, circa 2011)

Cave Story goes 3D, but remains a 2D side scroller...
Maybe a picture will help:

[image: a 3D kind of 2D]
[source: gamesradar](http://www.gamesradar.com/cave-story-remake-announced-for-3ds/)

**Changes include:**

- All levels and characters remade in 3D, with a "Classic mode" that puts the old 2D character sprites in the 3D world
- A "Dynamic camera system" that automatically zooms in at certain points in a level
- A few extra areas that were never included in the main game
- An unlockable "Time Attack Mode"
- A soundtrack remade by Danny Baranowsky of Super Meat Boy and Canabalt fame
- Numerous easter eggs for old fans of the game and "cross-over content" with nods to Prinny in the western version, and content from  Crazy Climber, Ikki, and Dragon Slayer added to the Japanese version

**Sources:**

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cave_Story#Versions_and_ports
- http://tinycartridge.com/post/1180342112/tiny-q-a-nicalis-on-cave-storys-jump-to-dsiware
- http://tinycartridge.com/post/1981857328/more-cave-story-for-dsi-owners-europeans
- http://gonintendo.com/?p=58121
- http://www.shacknews.com/article/71248/cave-story-now-available-via-steam
- http://www.destructoid.com/cave-story-3d-features-2d-sprites-nis-surprise-201157.phtml

Comment: "so assuming you don't want to know the specifics of the TI-83 plus calculator port" - Okay, now I really think I've seen everything. (Amazing answer, by the way. :D)

Comment: Does the Wii version actually have HD graphics? Considering the console isn't HD I'd say that's overkill...

Comment: Whoops, good call. While the graphics were updated for the WiiWare version, they weren't fully "HD" until Cave Story+. Thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have the Wiiware version, and you have the option to enable the old graphics.

Comment: Good to know, I don't have the WiiWare version myself, so it can be hard to fact-check some things.

Comment: Worth mentioning Cave Story+ also has the remastered soundtrack from 3D as an option

Answer (score 6):

Consider this an update/continuation of [RedRiderX's excellent answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/79065/181240). It includes differences for Nintendo Switch (2017), 3DS eShop (2012), and free updates released for to Cave Story+ on Steam.

---

### Cave Story ([PC](http://www.cavestory.org/download/cave-story.php), 2004, Free)

The original one-man freeware release that started it all.

[image: PC Freeware - Title Screen]

#### Missing features:

- Multiple save files (All other versions have 3 save files)
- Selectable difficulty levels
- Multiple graphical/soundtrack options

#### Other notes:

- Never officially released in English

  - English fan translation released by [Aeon Genesis](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Aeon_Genesis)

---

### Cave Story (WiiWare, 2010, $12)

First retail release of Cave Story with updated graphics, music, and game modes.

[image: WiiWare - Title Screen]

#### Included features:

- Two graphics options: *Original* and *Remastered*
- Two selectable soundtracks: *Original* and *New*
- Hidden Jukebox Sound Test
- Unlockable option to play as Curly Brace
- Boss Attack and Sanctuary Time Attack modes
- Three selectable difficulty levels

---

### [Cave Story](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/6cZuKpCvNU-MSZqhYcXm2fm8YT95OXfB) (DSiWare, 2011, Unavailable [was $10])

A DS port of the 2004 original, with some of the new features from the WiiWare version thrown in.

#### Included features:

- Uses second screen as a map and inventory viewer
- A modified version of the "Boss Rush" game mode included in the WiiWare version
- Jukebox Sound Test

#### Missing features:

- *Remastered* graphics
- *New* soundtrack
- Boss Attack

#### Other notes:

- No longer available for sale after DSiWare shop shut down in March 2017

---

### Cave Story+ ([Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/200900/Cave_Story/)/[Humble Store](https://www.humblebundle.com/store/cave-story), 2011, $15)

Cave Story returns to PC in what was *previously* considered the definitive version of Cave Story. (This honor now belongs to the Switch port)

[image: Steam - Title Screen]

#### Features include:

- Two graphics options: *Original* and *Remastered*
- Three selectable soundtracks: *Original*, *New*, and *Remastered*

  - *Remastered* soundtrack added in free update (originally from Cave Story 3D)
- Native USB controller support
- Machine Gun Challenge mode (added in update)
- Steam Achievements

#### Missing features:

- 16:9 Widescreen support

#### Other notes:

- Jukebox sound test must be unlocked by beating Blood Stained Sanctuary in under 3 minutes on Normal or Hard

---

### Cave Story 3D (3DS, 2011, $40)

Full fledged remake of Cave Story with 3D graphics.

[image: Cave Story 3D - Title Screen]

#### Included features:

- Fully recreated 3D modeled graphics.
- *Remastered* soundtrack by Danny Baranowsky of Super Meat Boy and Canabalt fame.
- 3 exclusive areas: Egg Corridor Detour, Inner Wall, and Falling Tower.
- An unlockable "Time Attack Mode".
- Numerous easter eggs for old fans of the game and "cross-over content"

  - [Prinny Cap](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Prinny_Cap) from [Disgaea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disgaea) for Western version
  - Content from Crazy Climber, Ikki, and Dragon Slayer added to the Japanese version.
- 16:9 Widescreen display

#### Missing features:

- Option for original soundtrack
- Jukebox sound test mode

#### Other notes:

- Published by [NIS America](http://nisamerica.com/)
- Never reprinted or released digitally

---

### Cave Story ([3DS eShop](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/cave-story-3ds), 2012, $10)

Replacement/Direct port of the DSiWare port on the 3DS eShop.

*Not to be confused with Cave Story 3D, which also released on 3DS.*

[image: 3DS eShop - Title Screen]

#### Included features:

- Supports Stereoscopic 3D
- 16:9 Widescreen display
- Curly Story

#### Missing features:

- *New* and *Remastered* soundtracks
- Remastered graphics option

Fun fact: Amazon sells [digital eShop codes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01LZC7NOU) for this version, but mistakenly uses screenshots from Cave Story 3D.

---

### Cave Story+ ([Nintendo Switch](http://www.nintendo.com/games/detail/cave-story-plus-switch), 2017, $30)

Originally a near-direct port of 2011's PC release of Cave Story+. However, free updates have introduced additional features such as local co-op, making this the definitive version.

[image: Nintendo Switch - Title Screen]

#### Features include:

- Two graphics options: *Original* and *Remastered*
- Four selectable soundtracks: *Origanya**, *Cave Story+*, *Remastered*, and [*Famitracks*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_clOBc_wsRw)
- 16:9 widescreen display
- Machine Gun Challenge mode
- Local 2 player co-op
- Skippable cutscenes

<sub>*No, that's not a typo. The soundtrack is actually labeled in-game as Origanya.</sub>

---

#### Sources

- [Cave Story Wiki: Version differences](http://cavestory.wikia.com/wiki/Version_differences)