# What was the Japanese exclusive content in Cave Story 3D?

Tags: version-differences, cave-story

According to the [Game Releases](http://www.cavestory.org/game-info/game-releases.php) page on [cavestory.org](http://www.cavestory.org/), the Japanese version of Cave Story 3D included extra bonus content.

> Cave Story on the Nintendo 3DS (physical release) with new 3D graphics, new or expanded areas, slightly increased difficulty, new item locations, new music remixes and a time attack mode.
>
> **Japanese release exclusively contains crossover content from Crazy Climber, Ikki, and Dragon Slayer.**

This exclusive content was briefly mentioned in an [article by Siliconera](http://www.siliconera.com/2012/05/01/new-cave-story-3d-artwork-made-just-for-japan/).

> **The Japanese version of Cave Story 3D will have additional content.
>   Nippon Ichi included retro game collaborations with content from Ikki,
>   Dragon Slayer, and Crazy Climber.** Right now, Nippon Ichi is keeping
>   the details of these collaborations under wraps.

This content was also mentioned in [RedRiderX's Cave Story comparison guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/79052/181240), but once again, no real detail was given.

> Numerous easter eggs for old fans of the game and "cross-over content" with nods to Prinny in the western version, and **content from Crazy Climber, Ikki, and Dragon Slayer added to the Japanese version**

What Japanese exclusive crossover content was included in Cave Story 3D? Was the crossover content significant, or was it limited to minor easter eggs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this Siliconera article](http://www.siliconera.com/2012/07/05/cave-story-3d-has-falcom-crazy-climber-and-ikki-heroes-well-just-for-japan/), this bonus content comes in the form of alternative playable characters from the three games mentioned in the articles above:

> Cave Story 3D is set for release in Japan on July 25 and this version has a few guests not in the North American release.
>
> You can play Cave Story 3D as a handful of retro heroes like the protagonist from Falcom’s Dragon Slayer.
>
> [image: dragon slayer cameo]
>
> The lead character from Hamster’s arcade game Crazy Climber is in Cave Story 3D too.
>
> [image: crazy climber cameo]
>
> You can also play as one of the rebelling famers from Sunsoft’s Famicom game Ikki.
>
> [image: ikki cameo]